# How to disable Pinning in UI Grid in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, grid, angularjs-scope, response, angular-ui-grid

How to disable the pinning in UI Grid for AngularJs??
Even after setting enablePinning:false or enableGridMenu: false It is not work

app.js file:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning']);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
 $scope.gridOptions = {};

 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
 { name:'id', width:50, enablePinning:true, hidePinLeft: false, hidePinRight: true },
 { name:'name', width:100, pinnedLeft:true },
 { name:'age', width:100, pinnedRight:true  },
 { name:'address.street', width:150  },
 { name:'address.city', width:150 },
 { name:'address.state', width:50 },
 { name:'address.zip', width:50 },
 { name:'company', width:100 },
 { name:'email', width:100 },
 { name:'phone', width:200 },
 { name:'about', width:300 },
 { name:'friends[0].name', displayName:'1st friend', width:150 },
 { name:'friends[1].name', displayName:'2nd friend', width:150 },
 { name:'friends[2].name', displayName:'3rd friend', width:150 },
];

 $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
 .then(function(response) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
 });
}]);
```

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20203%20Pinning

Comment: No..it still shows pinning..

Answer (score 0):

Enable pinging property need to set for gridOptions to disable in overall all gird

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enablePinning:false
  };
```

Also can set the property to specific column, disbaled for name column in plunker

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KJUqAyUmEHdhLzNL)